# How to convert from utc to localtime in Django using query?

Tags: python

`AccessTime = models.DateTimeField()` ---- This is my model field

`AccessTime = datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)` ---- Used this to save data in my database and it is stored in local time

Now fetching data from this database i am getting utc time

```
notification_ob = UnauthorizedAccess.objects.all().order_by('-AccessTime')[:50]       
for ob in notification_ob: 
     time_local = ob.AccessTime.astimezone(get_localzone())
     date_time = time_local.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
```

--- This is my view.py and this code is working bt i need a direct query for conversion

Comment: USE_TZ = True, try using the above code in settings.py

Comment: I'd start with checking if get_localzone() indeed returns your desired time zone.